# C# Package Tyrrrz/YoutubeExplode returning error 403 for YouTube html5 videos but not for flash videos

Tags: c#, .net, html, flash, youtube

I'm trying to extract YouTube videos in .NET using Tyrrz's package [YoutubeExplode](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/YoutubeExplode). My program was running fine yesterday and I was able to download audio and video streams for both flash and html5 videos. But today, when I try to extract an html5 video using the package, it exits with the error `Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).` The code I'm using to get the video stream is:

```
var youtube = new YoutubeClient();
var video = await youtube.GetVideoInfoAsync("GemKqzILV4w"); //YouTube ID for random video
var stream = video.MixedStreams.OrderBy(s => s.VideoQuality).Last();
await youtube.DownloadMediaStreamAsync(stream, "C:\\Videos\\vid.mp4");
```

My theory is that YouTube is blocking my requests for html videos somehow but I'm not sure how I can fix this problem. Is there some way to send headers with YoutubeClient() in the package? Does anyone else have any experience using this package? I've tried YoutubeExtractor and libvideo and pretty much every other C# package for this type of thing but so far, YoutubeExplode is the only one that works with html5 videos. Any help or a feasible solution to this problem is much appreciated.

Comment: Does YoutubeExplode capture videos from any website? If Youtube-only then how does it differentiate between FLV file (Flash) and other formats like WebM (Google) and MP4 (MPEG)? What I mean is it shouldn't give FLV but not MP4. Also Youtube keeps mostly MP4, WebM and M4A files so I don't know how/where you get these FLV files from. **Make sure you're asking about right thing**

Comment: Is there any way to check value of `(s => s.VideoQuality).Last();`? It better not be HD cos the max video size of your link is **360p**. Maybe that's why high-res is not found?? If worse comes to worse... Just write your own code to load html of video page (as `String`) and then extract direct link from there. Look for `"adaptive_fmts"` and from there you can get direct link after parsing HTML entities and UTF encoding of texts (for example every `%26` becomes as `&` in final direct link, etc etc)

Answer (score 1):

First off, you really should ask project-specific questions on their github issue trackers. I usually respond to every issue within the same day.

Second, what do you actually mean "works for html5 videos but not for flash videos"? To my knowledge, Youtube doesn't serve flash videos anymore. Usually the 403 error code means that the stream's signature wasn't (correctly) deciphered. As of writing this post, all tests are passing and I'm able to properly get video info and download streams from the video in your post using the demo application.
[image]
That said, Youtube serves region-specific responses so it's possible that the response served to you wasn't correctly processed for some reason.
Can you make an issue on the [github issue tracker](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/YoutubeExplode/issues) so we can discuss what could be the problem and fix this potential bug?